# Composer require without dev-master

Tags: php, github, composer-php, package

I have pushed a public package on my github. But now I can't require that package to my project as normal, I must specify `dev-master` version for finding it. I have tried to set `"minimum-stability" : "stable"`, but It does not work. Also I have created release `v0.1` with path to `master` branch. 
What can I do for using my package just ran `composer require <vendor>/<package>` command?

My `composer.json` file:

```
{
    "name": "miragepresent/likeable",
    "description": "Quick likes support",
    "keywords": ["likes support", "laravel", "eloquent", "like", "likes relation", "likeable"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "support": {
        "issues": "https://github.com/MiragePresent/Likeable/issues",
        "source": "https://github.com/MiragePresent/Likeable"
    },
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "David Holovii",
            "email": "mirage.present@gmail.com"
        }
    ],
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "MiragePresent\\Likeable\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.0"
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "providers": [
                "MiragePresent\\Likeable\\LikeableServiceProvider"
            ]
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable"
}
```

Comment: Can you post your `composer.json` file? Can you also tell us what package it is, so we can try to reproduce and confirm the issue?

Comment: You must list it on https://packagist.org/

Comment: Or use, https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#vcs

Comment: @LawrenceCherone, Add your comment as answer, I will mark it as best.
I have submitted the package to packagist and it works. Actually I submitted it earlier, but hook was not installed. That's why I've deleted a packagist package and submitted it again and it works

Comment: Done, i've answered a little generically so it will maybe help others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Steps to add a public composer package.

Develop your package, and make sure you have a `composer.json`

```
{
    "name": "vendor/package",
    "description": "My awesome package",
    "license": "MIT",
    "keywords": ["awesome","keywords"],
    "homepage": "https://github.com/vendor/package",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Mr Developer",
            "email": "developer@example.com",
            "homepage": "http://example.com/"
        }
    ],
    "support": {
        "email": "support@example.com"
    },
    "require": {
        "additional/package": ">=0.1"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Package\\Namespace\\": "src"
        }
    }
}
```

Then push your code to your VCS.

Sign up to https://packagist.org and list it, by clicking [Submit](https://packagist.org/packages/submit) and entering your packages VCS url in the input box. Submit it and correct any errors thrown.

[image]

Once the package is added, go to your account and grab your API key: https://packagist.org/profile/

Then add a *service* on the VCS (github) so new tags notify packagist.

`https://github.com/vendor/package/settings/installations`

[image]

[image]

Then once complete, you should create a tag of your package:

`git tag -a v0.0.1 -m "First release"`

Then push that tag to the VCS:

`git push origin v0.0.1`

Then anyone can install your package simply by doing:

`composer require vendor/package`

Comment: @Arcesilas Whats your point? Has something changed that its done any other way?

Comment: Oh I seeee... I said webhook not service.. you know you could of edited it right?